# Subqueries/relationships in Realm Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've got two Objects:

```
Account: Object {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var valid: String?
}

Transaction: Object {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic var desc: String?
    dynamic var accountId: String?
}
```

What I'm trying to do is somehow link the two objects so when I do a query on the transactions "table", I can find out which transactions come from an account which is `valid`.

I've tried linking them with 
`let transactions = LinkingObjects(fromType: Transaction.self, property: "fromAccount")`
in the `Account` object and doing the inverse in the `Transaction` object. The best result I get is either an empty list or a null record.

I suppose the next question is, is there a way to do what I'm trying? I've also looked into subqueries but haven't had any luck with them (the documentation is super slim it seems for subqueries).

What I've done in the past is whenever a new transaction is created, it goes and fetches the full account object (using `accountId`) and stores it in that record but I feel there must be a better way. Surely.

Comment: You will need to add @ objc to each property (or @ objcMembers to the object) to ensure it's managed by realm. As is, you won't store any data in realm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions but your linkingObject is a good option. It's really going to come down to what kind of queries you want to run.

So, let's start with a super simple example that will allow you to query transactions for any that have a parent account where valid is 'true' - that addresses your question.

```
class Account: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var valid: String?
}

class Transaction: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var desc: String?
    @objc dynamic var accountId: String?
    @objc dynamic var parent_account: Account?
}
```

then create a couple of objects

```
let a0 = Account()
a0.name = "account 0"
a0.valid = "true"

let a1 = Account()
a1.name = "account 1"
a1.valid = "false"

let t0 = Transaction()
t0.desc = "trans 0"

let t1 = Transaction()
t1.desc = "trans 1"

t0.parent_account = a0
t1.parent_account = a1

try! realm.write {
    realm.add([t0, t1])
}
```

once that data is written, if you want transactions where the parent_account's valid property == 'true'

```
let results = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("parent_account.valid == 'true'")

for account in results {
    print(account.desc)
}
```

and the output is

```
Optional("trans 0")
```

Keep in mind this is very very basic and probably not going to work for your use case long term. Investigating LinkingObjects and inverse relationships will probably be a better solution but this should get you going.

Oh... probably making the active property a bool is going to be better than string.

Comment: Hey @Jay, thanks for the effort, I really appreciate it. What makes this complicated for me is the information is coming in from an API, so creating these objects is done in an unpredictable way. For example, when a Transaction object is created (on response of the API), the associated Account object might not yet be available (simply hasn't reached that part of the JSON yet). That means I can't assign it to the Transaction object yet :/

Comment: @ByronCoetsee Not sure I understand. *unpredictable way*? What does that mean? And what does *coming in from an API* mean? Are you importing data from a file? Perhaps the process in which the data is being acquired should be adjusted instead of trying to solve a chicken-egg conundrum? My answer does answer the question presented so maybe if you update the question with a more specific use case, we can help.